# Compile GMP in STM32 on windows

Tags: c, makefile, stm32, cross-compiling, gmp

I am using GMP library in my project. How can I cross-compile in STM32( on windows )? Below is the makefile specification for STM32

```
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m33

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=hard

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)
```

I tried using mini-gmp but it does not have all the functions I need. Also its giving me wrong results in the controller, however, when I test it in Unix based system ( gcc, clang in linux without the controller ) it just work fine.

Comment: And so, what happens when you try to build GMP?

Comment: I don't know how to cross-compile. any pointers on that? what i understand is if i somehow get the static library then it can work but tbh i have never done and have zero knowledge.

Comment: The easiest way would be to have an STM32 project (e.g. using CubeIDE) and add the sources to that. Presumably you'll have something like that anyway if you're going to be using this library for something.